# Building external dependency with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, external-project

I'm trying to compile a C++ project which depends on a 3rd party library, called *Foo* for example. I'm using the `ExternalProject_Add()` command in a CMakeLists.txt file for this purpose. However, this library has a dependency, called *Bar* for example, which must be built first. The source files of the *Bar* library are located in a subdirectory of the source directory of the *Foo* library. So, here's my question: how can I compile the *Bar* library and then, the *Foo* library with the `ExternalProject_Add()` command? Thank you very much for your help.

**Update:** I forgot to say that the *Foo* and *Bar* libraries are both CMake projects which require a configure step before the build step.

Comment: [ExternalProject_Add documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) says you can specify arbitrary number of build steps:  `Any of the other ..._COMMAND options can have additional commands appended to them by following them with as many COMMAND ... options as needed` followed by multi-step `BUILD_COMMAND` example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, if the *Bar* library needs a configure step, maybe I need an extra ```ExternalProject_Add()``` command to manage the *Bar* dependency, no?

Comment: `are both CMake projects` then why not use `add_subdirectory`?

Comment: or FetchContent ?
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html